# Picture GUI C# (Using picture boxes)

Tags: c#, user-interface, graphics, picturebox

is there a way to do a click event on a picture in the picture box??
(so that i can click on a picture and have stuff happen.)
Ive tried labels but there hard to use. 
Thanks for the help.

--Label Code--

```
namespace Today
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Code Here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a little confusing exactly what you are asking. Is this one fixed image that you want to break into hotspots in order to do specific functions or ? ....

Answer (score 0):

simple answer for you is just `double click` on the `PictureBox` control from the Visual Studio `Design View` , so that Visual Studio create an `Event Handler`  and `subscribe` it to `Click Event` of the `PictureBox` control.

or you can use from coding:

Try This:

```
namespace Today
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            pictureBox1.Click += pictureBox1_Click;
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Code Here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i mean like clicking a picture thats on the picturebox

Comment: @MahchinLizard: yes , this click event fires when you click on picture on the picturebox.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `Event Handler` for the `Click` event for the `Picturebox`. First, "subscribe" to the event in your constructor:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        pictureBox1.Click += pictureBox1_Click;
    }
```

Then, you can make a method called `pictureBox1_Click` by inserting this:

```
    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Code
    }
```

Edit: The `Click` event will fire when you click on an image displayed inside the `PictureBox`. Alternatively, you can subscribe to `MouseDown` or `MouseUp`.

Comment: i konw tho is there a way to click on a picture in the picturebox and do somthing. (for gui)

Comment: @MahchinLizard The PictureBox contains the picture that you display in it. If you click on that picture, this event will trigger, so you can do stuff in the method `pictureBox1_Click`.

Comment: but can you choose one image so that if it is clicked??

Comment: Could you rephrase that? If you meant to choose another image when the `PictureBox` is clicked: `((PictureBox)sender).Image = //image to set`. If you meant to get the image that was clicked on: `Image clickedImage = ((PictureBox)sender).Image;`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possibilities, your `PictureBox` can show an image with smaller size than the size of `PictureBox`, in that case you want that clicking only on the **Rectangle** of the image will fire the event `Click`. The other possibility is when your image is a transparent image, such as a wheel?, in that case clicking only on the **non-transparent part** of your image will fire the event, in other words, clicking on the transparent region won't fire the event. The following code assumes your situation is the latter, it's of course even harder to implement than the former:

```
public class PictureBoxX : PictureBox
{
    static PropertyInfo ImageRectangle;
    static PictureBoxX() {
        ImageRectangle = typeof(PictureBox).GetProperty("ImageRectangle",
                          BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    }        
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x202 || m.Msg == 0x201) {
            var imageRect = (Rectangle)ImageRectangle.GetValue(this, null);
            using (var bm = new Bitmap(imageRect.Width, imageRect.Height,
                         System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb))
            using(var g = Graphics.FromImage(bm)) {
                int x = (int) (m.LParam.ToInt64() & 0xffff) - imageRect.X;
                int y = (int) (m.LParam.ToInt64() >> 16) - imageRect.Y;
                var rect = imageRect;
                rect.Location = Point.Empty;
                g.DrawImage(Image, rect);
                if (!imageRect.Contains(x, y)) return;
                else {
                    Color c = bm.GetPixel(x, y); 
                    //I choose the threshold 30 for the alpha channel
                    //the ideal threshold is 0, it's up to you.
                    if (c.A < 30) return;
                }
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
PictureBoxX pic = new PictureBoxX();
pic.Image = someTransparentImage;
pic.Click += (s,e) => {
   MessageBox.Show("Clicked on image!");
};
```

Trying the code above, you will see that clicking only on the non-transparent of your image will fire the `Click` event and show the message `"Clicked on image!"`. Note that the `BindingFlags` is located in the namespace `System.Reflection`, you can add `using System.Reflection;` for convenience.